# SSD (HP EX900 M.2) Read Failure in Lenovo E590

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I recently bought E590 (six months ago) (1TB, 12 GB RAM) and added 120 GB HP SSD EX900 M.2. I installed the OS on SSD. Everything was working fine till two months and then one day suddenly my laptop froze and won't start again.  Upon running diagnostic at the Boot Menu, the SSD read test failed i.e. laptop was unable to read OS from SSD. I contacted the seller and it replaced the SSD with a new one.

I re-installed OS on the new SSD and everything was fine for another 4 months, and all of the sudden same thing happened again. Suddenly a blue screen appeared with the message the "your pc stopped working" and then it never started again. The same problem this time i.e. SSD read test failed. The Laptop is not booting from SSD.  Tried all system repair and related diagnostic but SSD is not readable.

Now I have no clue what to do. I spent a good amount of money on the Thinkpad for peace of mind while working, but no luck at that peace at all.

Tech Saints and Gurus, please help.

Storage Quick Hierarchical Diagnostics:

All test were passed except SSD read test

Device Read Test: Failed

Result Code: UHDF20020-UG8W8D

Comment: EX900: " High failure rate - non-existant warranty support" "failed after 5 months" * dont buy this" This is the first thing I see when this SSD is mentioned in reviews. You should clearly try another brand of SSD. Your Thinkpad has nothing to do with your error.

Comment: Were you able to grab the SMART data from the drive?

Comment: @JMY1000, the SSD sometimes showed in the boot menu and other times don't. But the system does not boot at all. Some times it tries to repair disk errors and other times showed a detection error.  Thus don't know how to grab SMART data in these circumstances.